# Same content value need to sum in- multidimensional array - using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, sum

I have multidimensional result of an array which contain number of array object, need to merge this result in single instance of array with unique value of `content` and sum of `total`. Like below desired result. Helps are definitely appreciated.

**Result Set**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [response_id] => 23598
            [choice_question_detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content] => How old are your.
                            [total] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [content] => Stadium.
                            [total] => 4
                        )
          ),
      [1] => Array
        (
            [response_id] => 23599
            [choice_question_detail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [content] => How old are your.
                            [total] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [content] => Stadium.
                            [total] => 1
                        )
          )    
 )
```

**Desired Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [content] => How old are your.
            [total] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [content] => Stadium.
            [total] => 5
        )
)
```

My current implementation attempts to do something like this:

```
$sum = array_reduce($data, function ($a, $b) {
    isset($a[$b['choice_question_detail']]) ? $a[$b['choice_question_detail']]['total'] += $b['total'] : $a[$b['total']] = $b;  
return $a;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is like this... is a bit nasty but it should work.

And of course there are a lot of room for optimization, it's up to you how to improve it.

```
$out = array();

    foreach($var as $row) {
        foreach($row['choice_question_detail'] as $detail) {
            $flag = false;
            $numkey = -1;
            foreach($out as $key => $x) {
                if($x['content'] == $detail['content']) {
                    $flag = true;
                    $numkey = $key;
                }
            }
            if(!$flag) {
                $out[] = array(
                     'content' => $detail['content'],
                     'total' => $detail['total']          
                );
            } else {
                $out[$numkey]['total'] = $out[$numkey]['total'] + $detail['total'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is like this

```
array (size=2)
   0 => array (size=2)
          'content' => string 'How old are your.' (length=17)
          'total' => int 7
   1 => array (size=2)
         'content' => string 'What is your name.' (length=18)
         'total' => int 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no native method to do this, write it yourself.

```
$merged = array();
foreach($responses["choice_question_detail"] as $question){
    if($merged_q=$merged[$question["content"]]){
        $merged_q["total"] += $question["total"];
    }else{
        $merged[$question["content"]] = $qeustion;
    }
}
$desired = array_values($merged);
```